# PIP and python -m pip doesnt work when I specify the version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have got a problem when I want to install a specific version of a python library since I updated pip to 10.0.0. I would like to install it back but I cant find it, so I am forced to use the whole command , but it doesnt let me to install specific version of python package, any idea how to do it ?

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install APScheduler==3.0.0
Collecting APScheduler==3.0.0


C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install pip APScheduler==3.0.0
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (10.0.0)
Collecting APScheduler==3.0.0


C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install APScheduler==3.0.0
Collecting APScheduler==3.0.0


C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install pymongo
Collecting pymongo
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/96/00951e252c6cad023b3fd60457b2ab1c1329073516086c7ac1b6833a439e/pymongo-3.6.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (286kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 286kB 1.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo-3.6.1
```

also this is the part of a pip error I am dealing with , so any help would be awesome ^.^ ( Tried few things from stack overflow but neighter of them worked )

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install APScheduler==3.0.0
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install APScheduler==3.0.0'
```

Comment: Try using the `--upgrade` flag.  `python -m pip install --upgrade APScheduler==3.0.0`.  It should work for downgrades as well

Comment: thabk you that one worked , would you mind to post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `--upgrade` flag.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade APScheduler==3.0.0
```

It should work for downgrades as well

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both `python.exe` and `pip` are available in the locations in which it is looking for them. The `pip` launcher program is failing to run the command that it's printing in the error, which is probably because it can't find the relevant files.

Alternatively, just run `pip` using `python -m pip` which seems to work fine.

Comment: both of them are aviable at the location , there are even pip3.6 and pip3 , but neighter of them works fine with selecting the specific version. I tried it with python -m pip , but as u can see above its just start callecting and then crashes ...

Comment: @DominikLašo Have you tried other packages with version numbers? That package without a version number? It might just be a faulty package.